# Can someone run malicious code while writing into .txt

Tags: php

I have a simple HTML contact form where a user inputs their details by PHP scripting and is saved into a text file. What I want to know is whether it would be possible for someone to hack into the website.

Comment: They can hack using another approaches, for example CSRF

Comment: Without seeing your code, nobody can say whether it's save or not.

Comment: Bascialy they cannot hack while data is being written into the text file

Comment: @DavidY — CSRF is only a concern if the form should be accessible only authenticated users. There is no suggestion of that in the question.

Comment: I am not sure why people are down voting this question, does it seem simple, stupid or difficult to answer.  Either way down voting is not the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing to a text file doesn't introduce any direct attack vectors.

It is possible to write flawed code to write to a text file which introduces attack vectors (particularly if you accept a file name as user input).

Things you do with the text file later (such as making it public with certain content-types) might.

Comment: Its simple data such as name,email,telephone number and request of info thats submitted by a HTML form

Comment: @X10nD that's just the expected data. You never know what a user might submit.

Comment: So is there a way of checking.  Like we can check in sql injection?

Comment: @X10nD — That doesn't make any sense. To defend against SQL injection you escape (or use prepared statements to let the database server escape) the data so data with special meaning in SQL is rendered harmless. Text files don't have any characters with special meaning. See the first paragraph of this answer. Then see the last paragraph this answer. How you escape for "things you do with the text file later" would depend on what those "things" are.

Comment: So there is no danger in someone doing a hack.
Also I said "Like we can check in sql injection" not use sql injection.

Comment: Again, see everything I said in the answer. Writing to a text file is not intrinsically dangerous. Various things you can do around that can be.

Comment: The file name is not made public, the public does not know the locaiton of the file or how it can be accessed.